# A Hamiltonian with a potential depending on the momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, quantization, deformation-quantization

Imagine we have a Hamiltonian, whose potential depends on velocities (and hence on the momentum),

like, for example,
$$ H= \frac{p^{2}}{2m}+ V(x,p)$$
then how can I quantize that?

Comment: Do you mean how to perform second quantization?

Comment: Do you want to treat $V$ perturbatively?

Answer (score 4):

You have an embarrassment of riches, and you have to use symmetry or other physical information to restrict your choice! This is dubbed the "operator ordering ambiguity problem", and has been with QM since its inception.

There is *no* universal, unambiguous alchemical recipe for quantizing velocity-dependent potentials. One must choose a specific ordering of the non-commuting operators in it, and investigate the Hamiltonian for desired, or undesirable, properties. Hermiticity is not a sufficient constraint.

For the sake of illustration, consider a toy potential involving a piece $V(xp)=x^2p^2$.

Consider two of the most popular ordering prescriptions ("quantization rules"), [Weyl's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform#Weyl_quantization_of_polynomials),
$$
\mapsto \frac{1}{6} (\hat p ^2 \hat x ^2+  \hat x ^2\hat p ^2  + \hat p  \hat x ^2\hat p  +  \hat p  \hat x  \hat p  \hat x  +  \hat x  \hat p   \hat x  \hat p  +  \hat x  \hat p ^2 \hat x  ) 
\\ =\frac{1}{4} (\hat p ^2 \hat x ^2+ 2 \hat x ^2\hat p ^2  + \hat p  \hat x ^2\hat p )       ,
$$
that weighs every possible ordering by 1.

Alternatively, Born-Jordan's,
$$
\frac{1}{3} (\hat p ^2 \hat x ^2+  \hat x ^2\hat p ^2  + \hat p  \hat x ^2\hat p ).
$$
Both are Hermitian, but they differ (compute the difference using the commutation relation!),  while corresponding to the same classical limit.

(For readers interested in such things, the Husimi quantization ordering of the above amounts to the above Weyl ordering plus two extra pieces vanishing in the classical limit,
$ - \hbar (\hat p^2  +\hat x ^2)/2  + \hbar^2/4$ . The point is that there in an infinity of such prescriptions, none objectively superior to the others.)

- Combined with other terms in  each prescription will dictate different spectra. Only the experiment you are modeling will tell you which one to choose!

Or else, a most powerful guide in choosing an ordering prescription is symmetry. In his epochal [1926 matrix mechanics solution](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01450175) of the Hydrogen atom, (W Pauli, “On the hydrogen spectrum from the standpoint of the new quantum mechanics”, *Z Physik* **36** 336-363 (1926), reprinted in B L Van der Waerden, *Sources of Quantum Mechanics* (Dover, New-York, 1968)), Pauli chooses the obvious Hermitian quantization rule in his all-important Runge-Lenz vector,
$$
{\mathbf  p\times L} \mapsto (\hat{\mathbf p}\times \hat{\mathbf   L}-  \hat{\mathbf L}\times \hat{\mathbf p})/2
$$
that satisfies the [QM commutation relations of the crucial extended Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Runge%E2%80%93Lenz_vector#Quantum_mechanics_of_the_hydrogen_atom). (NB, Geeky:  <sub>You can check that, despite appearances, there is no ordering ambiguity here, since the coordinates multiply momenta of different directions, so you don't need any of the above prescriptions, and canonical quantization suffices. All of these prescriptions' deformation quantizations will produce the same algebra through associativity of their respective star products. Nevertheless, **L**² will be offset from its classical counterpart for all such prescriptions, as Pauli would have understood if he cared—but he did not have to. He just worked out his celebrated offset by commuting his operators just fine. Without star products (deformation quantization), however, most of these prescriptions would miss the offset and all fail!</sub>)